# competitive Programming: what is wrong in my code? my code is run successfully but code is not going to submit

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Given an integer N, write a program to print true if it is a perfect number or false if it is not a perfect number.
> (A perfect number is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its positive divisors, excluding the number itself.)
> The first line contains the number of test cases
> T.Each test case contains an integer N is provided.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> 2
>
> 28
> 96
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> true
> false.
> ```

I tried a lot but can't able to figure out what the problem is.
Here is my code:

```
a = int(input())
list1 = list()
for i in range(0,a):
  n = input()
  list1.append(n)
list2 = [int(j) for j in list1]
sum=0
for k in list2:
  for i in range(1,k):
    if k%i==0:
      sum = sum+i
    else:
      pass
  if sum==k:
    print('true')
  else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: @JohnColeman well, the loop makes sense because `input` is newline delimited, and the input will be newline delimited...

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting the variable `sum` after each iteration.
You need to do it, of course, otherwise you'll end up with only the first `k` being correct.

```py
for k in list2:
  sum=0 # !!!
  for i in range(1,k):
    if k%i==0:
      sum = sum+i
    else:
      pass
  if sum==k:
    print('true')
  else:
    print('false')
```

There are some additional "style" issues, issues that don't influence the behavior of the code but worsen the readability of it. Since you're still learning the language, I don't think it's particularly important to point them all out.

Just as an example, you don't need to use the `else` condition at all when the condition `k%i==0` fails, since you're not doing anything in that case.